# Angular FormControl Pattern Validator not working with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angular, forms

I'm trying to have some restriction on a text input.

I want it to accept only :

- alphanumerical characters (a-z A-Z 0-9)
- 3 special characters (comma, dash, single quotation mark) : , - '
- A few accented characters : à â ç è é ê î ô ù û
- spaces

So I'm declaring a validator with a regex pattern to the input like this :

```
this.form.addControl('adresseLine2', new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(PatternValidatorEnum.ADRESS_CONTENT)));
```

And the `ADRESS_CONTENT` regex is as follows :

```
ADRESS_CONTENT = '^[A-Za-z0-9\',\-àâçèéêîôùû ]*$'
```

It seems to work fine, but, the input stays valid when I have uppercase accented characters like : `É`

I want it to accept only lowercase accented characters (`àâçèéêîôùû`)

And according to https://regex101.com/r/6vyA8H/1 : `dsdséàê  ké` should be a valid input but `dsdséàê  kÉ` should not.

However, both are considered valid on my input.

Also, my input accepts characters such as `.`, `;`, `/` when it shouldn't according to the regex.

What am I missing ? Also, there might be some cases I forgot in my regex.

Comment: `ADRESS_CONTENT = '[A-Za-z0-9\',àâçèéêîôùû -]*'` or `ADRESS_CONTENT = /^[A-Za-z0-9',\-àâçèéêîôùû ]*$/` will both work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not your expression but instead you using `Validators.Pattern()` with a string instead of a `RegExp` type, changing your expression from

`'^[A-Za-z0-9\',\-àâçèéêîôùû ]*$'`

to

`/^[A-Za-z0-9\',\-àâçèéêîôùû ]*$/`

will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this regex pattern?

```
/^(?!À-Ö)[A-Za-z0-9\',\-àâçèéêîôùû ]*$/
```

You can say exclude the Upper Accent characters. This regex supports all your inputs.

https://regex101.com/r/6vyA8H/2

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-8f5xmk